# Django==2.1.4 - Blog

Tags: python, django, blogs

I am doing django project 2.1.4 and getting the below errors, i searched and it seems that i fix errors one by one , but i managed to solve some.
However these i could find any clue.

### Error after runserver or migrate.

```
    (myenv) C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite>python manage.py runserver

Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001EC9271A0D0>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225,
in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserv
er.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 3
79, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 3
66, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 7
1, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, i
n check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, i
n check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in
 check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, i
n __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in
 url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, i
n __get__

res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in
 urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in inclu
de
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)

  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .import views
  File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from blog.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
  File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\forms.py", line 15, in <module>
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 243, in _
_new__
    "needs updating." % name
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute
 or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form CommentForm needs updating.
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)

  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .import views
  File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from blog.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
  File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\forms.py", line 15, in <module>
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\Users\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 243, in _
_new__
    "needs updating." % name
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute
 or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form CommentForm needs updating.
```

---

here i am just adding separately.

```
  File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('', include('blog.urls')),

  '
     path('', include('blog.urls')),
 '



   File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .import views

    '
    from .import views
    '



 File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from blog.forms import PostForm,CommentForm

'
from blog.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
'



File "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\blog_project\mysite\blog\forms.py", line 15, in <module>
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    '
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    '
```

How to fix this errors?

**UPDATE: CommentForm below**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Comment 
        fileds = ('author','text',) 
        widgets = { 
            'author':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}), 
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'editable medium-editor-textarea'}) 
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `CommentForm`. The traceback indicates that the `CommentForm` class is missing some mandatory attributes.

Comment: @Mahmoud - When you add the material to the question it is OK to delete the comment. Delete the comment by clicking the the red 'x' near the date/time of the comment.

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen from your `CommentForm`, you've spelt `fields` as `fileds`. Correct that to fix the issue:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Comment 
        fields = ('author','text',)  # Use correct spelling
        widgets = { 
            'author':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}), 
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'editable medium-editor-textarea'}) 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much i fixed these issue and fields and it is running 
now i am getting this error

Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @Mahmoud - best to submit a new question for that

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'fields' or 'exclude' attribute to your ModelForm.

```
# example model:
class Comments(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comment = models.TextField()
# forms:
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Comments
        exclude = ['first_name', ] 
        # or:
        fields = ['comments', ]
```